# NHibernate: How to save a new entity without overwriting the parent:

Tags: nhibernate

I'm wondering what the best design would be for persisteing a new child entity with NHibernate without accidentally overwriting the parent in the database.

The problem I have is that the child entity will look something like this:

```
class Child
{
    Parent Parent; 
    // other fields
}
```

My problem is that the child has been supplied from the UI layer along with the ID of the parent, and that means that the Parent ref is basically uninitialized: It will have the ID populated but everything else null - because the only way to populate its fields would be an extra round trip to the database to read them.

Now if I call `Session.SaveOrUpdate(child)` on NHibernate, what's going to happen with the parent. I don't want NHibernate to cascade save the uninitialized parent since that would just destroy the data in the database.  How would people approach this problem? Any best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your models looks like this

```
class Parent 
{

}


class Child
{
     Parent myParent;
}
```

and you are trying to set the parent and save the child without having a full parent object, just the ID.

You could try this:

```
session.Lock(child.myParent, LockMode.None);
```

before saving, this should tell nhibernate that there are no changes to the parent object to persist and it should only look at the object for the Id to persist the association between Parent and Child

Answer (score 3):

You must use the session.Load(parentid) to get the aggregate root. In contrast to the session.Get() method, this does not actually fetch any data from the database, it just instantiates a Parent proxy object used to add Child objects to the correct Parent in the DB (eg. get the foreign key correctly).

Your code would probably look something like:

```
// Set the Parent to a nhibernate proxy of the Parent using the ParentId supplied from the UI
childFromUI.Parent = Session.Load<Parent>(childFromUI.Parent.Id);
Session.Save(childFromUI);
```

[This article explains Get/Load and the nhibernate caches really well](https://web.archive.org/web/20110514214657/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate.aspx)

Comment: +1; interesting link, but I found http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/30/nhibernate-ndash-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by.aspx a more concise reference on the differences on Get vs Load.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be working with the aggregate root (probably the Parent) when doing Saves (or SaveOrUpdates etc).

Why not just:

- Fetch the parent object using the parent id you have in the child from the UI layer
- Add the child to the parents 'children' collection

Comment: OK thanks. That would imply an extra round-trip to the database to fetch the parent, even though I'm not intending to do anything with the parent data, which I'd have preferred to avoid. There isn't any good way to avoid that?

Comment: Use Load() as Trygve suggested to avoid loading needless data.

Comment: It sounds like what is happening is children are being populated directly into the UI by a query without any regard to the parent.  What is being suggested is a general principle of design in which you never have children outside of the parent.  You certainly do not add new children without going through the parent.

Comment: (Got cut off).  Like looking in rear view and there is a third kid who calls you dad.  Who is he, where did he come from, human or alien and will your wife be pregnant in the am with what?  Aggregates extend this concept beyond parent/child to logical sets of objects that form a single unit of data transactions.  Only aggregate roots are obtained by query directly.  A child is always aggregated at minimum to it's parent who provides the only access.  If parent is part of an aggregate root, it would only be accessed by the root.  Access is by traversal, aggregate represents 1 data work unit.

Comment: Yep, that is all true. And of course in the situation I'm describing, the user interface would a few minutes previously have got the parent from the DB. But now the user has specified the child to create and which parent to attach it to, there seems no point having the UI pass full details of the parent back to the backend - that would require us to put an expensive object graph into our dtos, which we don't want. Hence the backend ends up with full details of the child to be added, but only the ID of the parent.

Comment: Depends on mappings, you may be able to just set the parentId on the child explicitly and then save only the child and flush. Have you tried that?  With DTOs you can also get child from parent and send child DTO alone to UI.  Full parent dto not required, maybe none. Then one of various designs allow actual parent to ultimately update child.  You pull more data by getting parent to get child but more trips not rqd.   Aggregates are about creation/state changes are in one place only where rules and invariants are always enforced,not about trips/minimum resources.  Not all need/buy into it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to overview your **mapping configuration** for nhibernate. If you have defined on the reference by the child to the parent that hi has to Cascade all, it will update it!
So if you say **Cascade.None** he will do nothing. All other are bad ideas. Because you allready has the information of this parent. So why read from db agane?!